# From where can I download the source code for Eclipse 1.0?

Tags: eclipse

I need to download the source code for Eclipse 1.0, but I don't know from where.

The [Eclipse project archive page](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) contains the build/binaries for 1.0 but not the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse-SDK download in the archive page for 1.0 [here](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-1.0-200111070001/) contains a zip file in each plug-in directory 'xxxxsrc.zip' with the source code.